# Android ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE intent is not sending to Google Drive

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am firing an ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE intent, which for some reason is offering Google Drive as one of the options to handle this intent. However, when I select Google Drive as my choice, nothing happens. No error message, no anything. I have the following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
intent.setType("message/rfc822");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "My subject");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "My text");
startActivity(intent);
```

Selecting Google Drive works just fine when using the ACTION_SEND intent, however. What is going wrong, and why? Ideally I would have Google Drive not show up at all as an option, but I haven't found a solution yet that works with this specific intent.

Comment: If nothing else, you are not following the rules for `ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE`. The `EXTRA_TEXT` extra needs to be an `ArrayList<String>`, not a single `String`. For that, use `ACTION_SEND`.

Comment: What's the problem with not using an ArrayList? It works just fine when I use Strings (and I choose an actual mail app to handle my intent).

Comment: "What's the problem with not using an ArrayList?" -- the fact that apps, written to follow [the documented protocol](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE), will not expect a string. When they call `getStringArrayListExtra()`, they will get `null` back, and they will not work properly. "It works just fine when I use Strings" -- the apps that you tried happen to gracefully degrade and handle a `String` for `EXTRA_TEXT`. Please do not assume that all apps will be so gracious when dealing with a malformed `Intent`.